# org-mode source block: conditional header

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

How can I modify the header of a source block dynamically, based on the backend used to export my org-mode document? Specifically, I want the header to include `:results output html` when the file is exported to HTML, and `:results output latex` when the file is exported to LaTeX.

I believe that I should use the `org-export-current-backend` variable to achieve this, but I have been unable to write a header that does what I need.

For example, I think I could include an `if` call in the header. Unfortunately, this example triggers the HTML build correctly but not the LaTeX one (I can successfully export to LaTeX by inverting the `if` conditional):

```lisp
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports both :results output (if (eq org-export-current-backend 'html) html latex)

(if (eq org-export-current-backend 'html)
  (princ "<ul><li>Green tea</li><li>Black tea</li></ul>")
  (princ "\\begin{itemize}\n\\item Green tea\n\\item Black tea\n\\end{itemize}"))

#+end_src
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find a direct answer to my question, so I turned to an alternative that works almost as well as what I had in mind: Org-Mode Macros. In this example, we use the `conditional-header` macro to "decorate" the source block and dynamically change the header based on the output format. This org-mode document thus exports automatically to both PDF and HTML without altering the code.

```lisp
#+MACRO: conditional-header (eval (concat "#+header: :results output " (prin1-to-string org-export-current-backend)))  

{{{conditional-header}}}
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports both
(if (eq org-export-current-backend 'html)
  (princ "<ul><li>Green tea</li><li>Black tea</li></ul>")
  (princ "\\begin{itemize}\n\\item Green tea\n\\item Black tea\n\\end{itemize}"))
#+end_src
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you just needed to add quotes around the values `html` and `latex` in the header elisp snippet as follows:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :exports both :results output (if (eq org-export-current-backend 'html) "html" "latex")

(if (eq org-export-current-backend 'html)
  (princ "<ul><li>Green tea</li><li>Black tea</li></ul>")
  (princ "\\begin{itemize}\n\\item Green tea\n\\item Black tea\n\\end{itemize}"))

#+end_src
```

Then the code block seems to generate the right results depending on the `org-export-current-backend` variable.

Comment: Thanks for giving this a shot! Unfortunately, the code does not seem to be rendered properly when exported to PDF or HTML. The correct code appears in a source "block", but as raw html or LaTeX rather than a properly formatted list.