# Is it possible to do #+SETUPFILE conditionally in orgmode (with regard to included files)?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex-header

I'm working on a big text in orgmode, which is expected to be finally exported to Latex & PDF, so I made this kind of a master document in orgmode:

```
#+SETUPFILE: exportoptions.org
#+INCLUDE: "01.org"
#+INCLUDE: "02.org"
```

so I can work on individual chapters. Each of those also has

```
#+SETUPFILE: exportoptions.org
```

at the top, so I can check the final result as I go.
Only now I'm unable to export the master document as some of those options block Latex-ing when included more than once.

Is it possible to conditionally process the #+SETUPFILE directive, e.g. to ignore it when it's used in included files? I've thought `:only-contents t` would help,  but no.

Comment: Not that I know of: you'll have to delete (or comment out) the `#+SETUPFILE: ` lines in all the included files.

Comment: I was sort of hoping for some clever elisp trick to do that on the fly. I've seen some in the context of this SE, only I don't understand them.

Comment: If you provide links, I can take a look at them.

Comment: You can of course use tools to delete (or comment out) those lines: either on the command line with `find` and `sed` (on Linux or other *nix systems) or using Emacs [search and replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search.html) facitilities

Comment: Yes, of course I can construct a Makefile and use GNU text utilities. That remains an option anyway. Only I was thinking about something on the lines of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/64340/30404. Maybe a similar sort of trick could be provided in my case. Me, I can't go anywhere from there. No knowledge of orgmode internals at all.

Comment: Which `#+KEYWORDS: ` give a conflict ... Share the keywords that give a conflict.  How  `KEYWORD` is handled depends on the nature of the keyword.  Some are overridden, some are merged, some are parsed  etc.  Share minimal work example of your `SETUPFILE`.

Comment: Actually, I don't know precisely what produces a show-stopping error. Xelatex just freezes at CPU 100% at some moment. The processed .tex file (as produced by org) is 400+K but the TeX preamble converted from org defaults and my additions isn't that large, just repeated 8 times. In the .log there are lots of 'command already defined but the error is ignored'. While a set of short org files with the same structure and the same preamble repeated 8 times in .tex file IS able to finish i.e. produce a PDF.